# Intel Realsense Cameras for Object Avoidance and SLAM to go to destination

Tags: slam, computer-vision, imu, uav

My goal is to make a UAV which can search an area while avoiding obstacles. I figured I would navigate using the SLAM and Intel Realsense D435i (a stereoscopic camera with an IMU built in), but all of Intel's examples seem to use D435i for object avoidance, but another camera, the T265 for navigation. Am I missing something about these cameras that would make this application necessary to contain both cameras? And if not, are there any suggestions for resources to look at to achieve this goal?